# Is this objective-c variable initialize fashion correct?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

What will happen behind the screen if I alloc a array using this piece of code? Is it a good fashion or any disadvantages? In my project, if I have something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
array = [array arrayByAddingObject:@"Hi"];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Output: Hi

But if I do this way:

```
@property (assign) NSArray *filesInfo;

switch (streamEvent) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
        self.filesInfo = [NSArray array];
        self.didOpenStream = YES;
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
        break;
    }
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
        data = [self.streamInfo read:self];

        if (data) {
            [self.receivedData appendData:data];
        }
        else {
            [self.streamInfo streamError:self errorCode:kGRFTPClientCantReadStream];
        }
        break;
    }

    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
    break;

    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
        [self.streamInfo streamError:self errorCode:[GRError errorCodeWithError:[theStream streamError]]];
        break;
    }
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
        NSUInteger  offset = 0;
        CFIndex     parsedBytes;
        uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)[self.receivedData bytes];
        NSUInteger totalbytes = [self.receivedData length];

        do {
            @autoreleasepool {
                CFDictionaryRef listingEntity = NULL;
                parsedBytes = CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(NULL, &bytes[offset], totalbytes - offset, &listingEntity);
                if (parsedBytes > 0) {
                    if (listingEntity != NULL) {
                        self.filesInfo = [self.filesInfo arrayByAddingObject:(__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)listingEntity];
                    }
                    offset += parsedBytes;
                }
            }
        } while (parsedBytes > 0);

        [self.streamInfo streamComplete:self];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

after the line 5 got triggered, the filesInfo type becomes to   NSConcreteMutableData type.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This "works" but doesn't make a lot of sense. You've created a mutable array, but declared it immutable. What you meant was:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

or you meant:

```
NSArray *array = @[]; // The same as [NSArray array]
```

This code is a bit strange, though it will also work:

```
NSArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
array = [array arrayByAddingObject:@"Hi"];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

You're creating a mutable array, but then treating it as an immutable array. You really should use one pattern or the other. Make it immutable (`@[]`) or use the mutability:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:@"Hi"];
```

This is very broken and dangerous:

```
@property (assign) NSArray *filesInfo;
```

Using `assign` here is creating undefined behavior when `filesInfo` is released (since you're not holding onto it). You can't really bet on anything about this variable given how you're using it. You meant:

```
@property (strong) NSArray *filesInfo;
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's very broken and dangerous. That code snippet in my project was written 2011 by others and it seems to imitating the Java variable declaration fashion. Something like: Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();